# Limiting overflow on ticker text CSS

Tags: html, css, overflow, padding, margin

[visual aid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRn24.png)

I would like to limit the text at the very bottom (below current match text that stretches all the way along). So that it only shows up in the bracketed area.

The ticker therefore moves to the left slowly. I would like the text to be revealed just after the OPL logo then disappear when it reaches the 'CURRENT MATCH...' text. As shown by my red lines that indicates the end.

Here is my current CSS for that div

```
.crawler__crawl-text {
    padding-right: 100px;
    padding-left: 100px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-variation-settings: 'wdth' 80,'wght' var(--font-weight);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 10px;
    line-height: 25px;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: var(--color4);
    position: absolute;
    left: 1910px;
    font-family: bison, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

I have tried searching online for options but had no luck. Padding and margins seem to have no effect so I'm sure there is something simple I am missing.

Comment: Please share html also

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/2518285) which demonstrates the problem